# CSS: Center fixed Button horizontally, and animate Margin Top.

Tags: jquery, css

I´m stuck here on a problem. I feel like my css knowledge has come to an end once and for all. 
My problem is following.
As you can see in the picture i have a fixed header, a header bar and a button, all floating on top of other content, not moving if the user scrolls.

[image: What i´m able to do]

```
.headerBarGreen {
        background-color: #7ac4a7;
        width: 100%;
        height: 5px;
        margin-top: 70px;
        position: fixed;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2px #000000;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #000000;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #000000;
        z-index: 1000;


}

.button {
        background-color: #7ac4a7;
        color: #ffffff;
        width: 70px;
        position: fixed;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 75px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
        border-top-right-radius: 0px !important;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px !important;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px !important;
        font-family:'poetsenoneregular', sans-serif !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -3px #2c2929;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -3px #2c2929;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -3px #2c2929;
        z-index: 1000;
}
```

**Now i want the header bar and the button to move down opening up a dropdown.
Well that works just fine for the header bar, but not for the button.**

I believe the reason is because i use the margin: 0 auto, property to center the button horizontally. 
I tried severel things which all failed:

I put the button in a div with width 100% and margin top 75px. 
The button then had no margin top, just a margin 0: auto; 
Of course it was floating on top of the page, as suspected.

I also tried to remove the position: fixed attribute from the button and only put it 
in the container. What happened was, that the button only floated to the left now.
The margin top was right though.

Last thing i tried was to put the position:fixed button with a margin: 0 auto in a container with a margin-top 75px, also with a fixed position. 
Now the picture looks just like what i showed you.

In each case: **when i animate it the button just doesnt move down like the header Bar.**

**I animate the bar and the button like so:**

BAR:

```
$(".headerBarGreen").animate({marginTop: "390px"}, 500);
```

BUTTON:

```
$("#button").animate({marginTop: "395px"}, 500);
```

I´m happy for any help.

Thank you already. Cheers, Marvin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well luckily i already found the answer.

As you can see in my code i was trying to animate the button using its id.
I now tried animating the class i gave it and everything works like a charm.

question closed